ms access может ли быть (select...) в списке полей оператора select
select (select field from table where...)

Внутренний select возвращает единственный скаляр, тем не менее, реакция ms access 2007:


Наверное должно быть select * from (select f from ...)

Никак нет. select в скобках, возвращающий скаляр, должен трактоваться как выражение. По крайней мере так себя ведут другие известные sql серверы.
В частности оператор select 2*2 - вполне законный.
Это не единственный грех ms access.

В частности, выражение
case when врж11 then врж12... end
входящее в стандарт  ansi 92 в ms access не работает
